# Make table prettier with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a basic python script that scraps a webpage to copy a table and a single number (using xpath for both) and then sends that information by email.

But the table doesnt have a user friendly format since during the scrapt it loses the table lines. There is  easy way to make the table more pretty without have to scrap number by number and construct the table from beginning?

Even if I send the email as html, the data is all mixed. If send as text its readable (check on bottom) but anyway it's not very user friendly. Thanks.

My code is:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

with Display():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    try:
        url = 'https://pt.investing.com/commodities/brent-oil-historical-data'
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        brent_data = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='results_box']").text
        #print (brent_data)
        last_price = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='last_last']").text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        brent_data = "no data"
        last_price = "no data"
    finally:
        browser.quit()


import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now()
today = today.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')


text_send = """
========================================
%s

%s

========================================
""" % (last_price, brent_data)
```

The output is:

```
66,17

Data Último Abertura Alta Baixa Vol. Var. %
28.12.2017 66,17 65,97 66,33 65,97 - 0,38%
27.12.2017 65,92 66,20 66,38 65,48 - -1,64%
26.12.2017 67,02 65,20 67,10 65,00 74,25K 2,71%
22.12.2017 65,25 64,63 65,28 64,38 110,42K 0,54%
21.12.2017 64,90 64,49 64,93 64,20 155,42K 0,53%
20.12.2017 64,56 63,83 64,60 63,67 222,73K 1,19%
19.12.2017 63,80 63,41 63,91 63,30 213,19K 0,62%
18.12.2017 63,41 63,36 63,91 63,00 234,62K 0,28%
15.12.2017 63,23 63,39 63,68 63,08 213,00K -0,13%
14.12.2017 63,31 62,81 63,50 62,01 277,67K 1,39%
13.12.2017 62,44 63,80 64,32 62,36 354,37K -1,42%
12.12.2017 63,34 64,66 65,83 63,07 508,99K -2,09%
11.12.2017 64,69 63,29 64,93 62,99 488,01K 2,03%
08.12.2017 63,40 62,08 63,64 62,01 362,43K 1,93%
07.12.2017 62,20 61,30 62,26 61,15 238,96K 1,60%
06.12.2017 61,22 62,64 62,93 61,13 314,26K -2,61%
05.12.2017 62,86 62,45 63,15 62,12 219,34K 0,66%
04.12.2017 62,45 63,50 63,68 62,31 250,52K -2,01%
01.12.2017 63,73 62,74 64,32 62,59 308,15K 0,25%
30.11.2017 63,57 63,28 64,21 63,21 26,21K 0,73%
29.11.2017 63,11 63,30 64,07 62,50 178,20K -0,79%
28.11.2017 63,61 63,78 63,89 63,10 186,93K -0,36%
Alta: 67,10 Baixa: 61,13 Diferença: 5,97 Média: 63,83 Var. %: 3,65
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are allowed to copy the data following the Terms and Conditions of the site, you may be able to get the table itself.  Use an Xpath to the "table" element, then use

```
element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

then format your output as html.

Alternatively, one of their RSS feeds might work for you, then use a python package to grab that data.  (I have not used one myself, so I couldn't recommend any).